# Azure Fabric Cluster Error Publishing: Test- ServiceFabricApplicationPackage : It was not poss¡vel Find Part of Path

Tags: azure, cluster-computing, publish, azure-service-fabric

Everytime i click Publish i receive this error on the output window.

Test- ServiceFabricApplicationPackage : It was not possible to Find Part of Path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you perhaps have an ASP.NET 5 project in your application? There is a known issue where file paths for ASP.NET 5 projects included in Service Fabric apps get too long and fail in the Test-ServiceFabricApplicationPackage cmdlet during deployment. We have a fix for this coming in an SDK refresh coming soon. In the interim, the best you can do is to keep the name of your ASP.NET projects very short.

Comment: hey, thanks for the help, there is 2 projects as ASP.NET 5 inside, but the names are: CategoryService and GeolocationService

Comment: but anyway the problem still persist, do u think that names are too big?

Comment: Might be - it depends on a few factors. As I said, we'll have an update out shortly that will fix it. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Can you tell me after you launch the fix where can i download it? 

Thanks man, keep up the good work!

Comment: Now im receiving an error:

The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less then 260 characters, and the dicrectory name must be less than 248 characters.

The full path: 
D:\Personal Projects\Capslock Studios\Woodioo\Gateway\HttpServiceGateway.sln
so 76 characters.

Comment: Are you seeing that as a VS dialog?

Comment: yeah, i just change the path on my disk, from "Personal Projects" to "PP" and "Capslock Studios" to "CS" and i could upgrade the project, but when i try to publish the project i get the error:

Comment: Copying application to image store...
Copy application package succeeded
Registering application type...Register-ServiceFabricApplicationType : Operation timed out.
At C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service 
Fabric\Tools\PSModule\ServiceFabricSDK\Publish-NewServiceFabricApplication.ps1:218 char:9

Comment: Register-ServiceFabricApplicationType -ApplicationPathInImage 
CategoryInfo          : OperationTimeout: (Microsoft.Servi...usterConnection:ClusterConnection) [Register-Servic 
eFabricApplicationType], TimeoutException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : RegisterApplicationTypeErrorId,Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Powershell.RegisterApplicationType

Comment: If you see the long path issue in the VS dialog, go to your application project in Windows Explorer and delete the backup/bin/obj folders and try again. This is called out as a known issue in the announcement blog.